# Is it okay to say that $|{x}|=\sqrt{x^2}$ in a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While analyzing a certain function I was asked to integrate $$\int \left|f'\left(x\right)\right|f\left(x\right)dx$$ Since I don't know how to integrate an absolute value function, I noticed that it could be re-written as $$\int \sqrt{f'\left(x\right)^2}f\left(x\right)dx$$ and evaluated that integral, which gave me the correct answer. My question is, can you do that for every function? And how is $\sqrt{f'\left(x\right)^2}$ different than $f'\left(x\right)$? It's supposed to be just $$\left(f\left(x\right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = f\left(x\right)$$ Isn't it?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ is true. $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ is, in the most general cases, false

Comment: The general strategy for integrating absolute value functions is in evaluating separately on the positive and negative regions.

Comment: Speaking to your last question, $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ is an identity when $b$ is an integer, but as soon as you consider more general exponents, you'll quickly find cases where that equality fails.  This is required as soon as we define $x^a$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: $x^a$ as a function of $x$, or $a^x$ as a function of $x$?

Comment: @BrianTung For that equality, the important fact is we define $x^a$ as a function of $x$.  For instance, setting $a=1/2$, we state that $x^{1/2}$ is a function of $x$.  If I set $x=4$ in this function, I only get one value out.  Depending on your decision, it could be $2$ or it could be $-2$, but once I make that decision, it's fixed.  I can't have it equal $-2$ in one line and $2$ in the next because then I'm talking about two different functions.

Comment: More abstractly, call $x \mapsto x^a$ the function $\varphi_a$.  Then $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ is the statement $\varphi_b \circ \varphi_a = \varphi_{ab}$.  Once we define these three functions, we have equality or not, and some functions, like $\varphi_{1/2}$, have more than one candidate.

Comment: Your last question leads me to suspect you took an unwarranted shortcut in evaluating $\int \sqrt{f'\left(x\right)^2}f'\left(x\right)dx.$ Perhaps it turns out you're taking the square of something that is already guaranteed to be positive. What particular function is $f'$ in this integral?

Comment: @BrianMoehring: I think I just misunderstood what you were saying, thinking that you were claiming that defining $x^a$ (as a function of $x$) was a problem for any $a$.